# Is it possible to buy one photoshop and use virtualization in a way that everyone can use it?

Tags: virtualization, adobe-photoshop, licensing

Is it possible to install a main server and install some sort of virtualization technology, pay one price for software such as Photoshop and let everyone user it?

Please explain to me why or why not

If yes, please tell me what technologies are capable of doing that, and one would save costs by doing that.

How will the performance be?

I noticed this guy has done that
http://www.dabcc.com/article.aspx?id=13073

I was wondering if this is a good idea at all or not?

Comment: Apparently (Just starting looking into this myself) You can get a server license for Adobe desktop products according to this thread: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/442781 But it is a bit vague.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While all the other answers just say "It's a violation of the [Photoshop EULA](http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/pdfs/Gen_WWCombined-20110105_1512.pdf)!" lets actually take a look.

First in the section `1.Definitions` we need to clarify a few things (page 106 for the US English version) so we can understand the further sections.

> "Computer" means a **virtual** or physical computer device that accepts
>   information in digital or similar form and manipulates it for a
>   specific result  based on a sequence of instructions
>
> "Internal Network" mean  a private, propietary network resource accessible only by employees and individual contractors (i.e., temporary employees) of a specific corporation or similar buisness entity. Internal Network does not include portions of the Internet or any other network community open to the public, such as membership or subscription driven groups, associations, and similar organizations.
>
> "Output File" [...]
>
> "Permitted Number" means one (1) unless otherwise indcated under a valid 
>   license (e.g., volume license) granted by adobe.

*Emphasis mine*. So if we have multiple copies of the VM running it is considered multiple "Computers", good to know.

`Section 2.2` (pg 107 for English)

> 2.2 General Use. Execpt as described otherwise herein, you may install and use one copy of the Software in accordance with the Documentation
>   only on the Permitted Number of your compatible Computers into which
>   you enter a valid serial number.

Drat, so we can't run the VM multiple times as that would count as mutiple computers. Hey, what if we installed in on somthing like Windows Server, where multiple people can be logged in at the same time on the same computer. `2.2` does not mention anything about that! (This "Server" solution is what the guy is doing in the link you posted in your original question)

Section 2.4 (still pg 107)

> 2.4 Server Use. You may install the Software on the Computer file server(s) within your Internal Network only for the use of the
>   Software initiated by an individual from a Computer within the same
>   Internal Network only as permitted by Section 2.1 or 2.2 (as
>   applicable). The total nubmer of users (not the concurrent number of
>   users) able to use the Software on such Computer file server(s) may
>   not exceed the Permitted Number.

Damn, they still got us. Also its good to know that you need a license for every user who will be using the program, not just the number of people using it at the same time (This in the software industry is called [Per User licensing vs Per Seat licensing](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.401722.4))

So it appears that your idea will not work and indeed it really is "a violation of the Photoshop EULA".

Answer (score 5):

It's illegal. You can use one license at two your computers only. Read the agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Unless only one user is trying to access it. In may case, I use a Chromebook because it's fully integrated with Google, unlike my Mac. So I want to remotely access my Photoshop and Illustrator instances remotely from my Chromebook.

That being said, is anyone else able and willing to explain how to virtualize them?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, is you would be breaking the license agreement you made when you purchased the software and passing it to others would be illegal.