# Run Photoshop on VM (virtual machine) to increase calculation power, without violating the licence agreement (EULA)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, adobe-photoshop, licensing

A question concerning the possibility to run [Photoshop as VM without violating the license agreement (EULA)](https://superuser.com/questions/406828/is-it-possible-to-buy-one-photoshop-and-use-virtualization-in-a-way-that-everyon) : My Adobe Photoshop is very slow, and sometimes I need to launch thousands of image calculations that have to use hundreds of PSD templates. I want to increase my Photoshop calculation power by creating non-persistent virtual machines on my hosted server. Each VMm would only alive for a few seconds, just enough time to deliver the calculated file. Is this a violation of the EULA? I must clarify that I'm the only one to access my non persistent VMs.

Comment: sorry but licensing questions are offtopic for [su]

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/406828/) for the answer.

You can install and use only one copy of Photoshop.

In short, you're violating.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is an efficient way to do this. Your created VMs would need to boot up or at least come out of suspension, and you have the whole issue of running an entire OS to do the whole thing.

You're going to end up with a whole load of low powered, really lousy machines that arn't taking advantage of the whole server power. If you want speed, go native, and spin up as many instances of photoshop as there are threads (unless PS is multithreader).

*Even* if it was legal, you're unlikely to see a major speed up from this approach, *especially* starting and destroying VM instances like that.

Even if the only tool you have is a jackhammer, one does not use it to crack a walnut.